# Eliminate possibility of belated data manipulations on MySQL table

Tags: mysql, hash, database-trigger

I want to guarantee that the rows in my MySQL table cannot be manipulated after their creation.

I know that only granting insert and select privileges is one step in this direction, but I also want to make sure the root user cannot alter data after insertion.

**Incremental hashing:**
To this end, I think about an additional column 'hash', that stores the hash value of the last row's hash concatted with the new column data.

If I then export the hashes eg. every day, any manipulation could be detected.

Am I right? Can you point me to some resources where this has been done already? Would one do this with a trigger? Maybe even in an auxiliary table that is only accessible by root?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_hash
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
UPDATE table_name
SET hash = MD5(concat(NEW.field1, NEW.field2, NEW.field3, ...))
WHERE id= NEW.id
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that goes into the right direction. However, I want to incorporate the  hash of the last row as well, like `set new.hash := SHA2(CONCAT(NEW.f1, NEW.f2,..., (select hash from table where id = last_insert_id())),256)`

Comment: i don't understand your comment, you want to add the hash of the previous line in the new line ?

Comment: Yes! That way any later data manipulation could be detected (as long as the hash is stored from time to time)

Comment: I still don't understand the point to insert the hash in another hash

Comment: Well assume somebody has access to the database and manipulates eg. field1. The detection of this could be detectable easily, right? If I would not include the previous hash, an attacker could just recompute the hash.